# Remove Extra back slash "\" from string file path in c#

Tags: c#, .net, string

How to convert

`"String path = @"C:\Abc\Omg\Why\Me\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\";`

into

`String path = @"C:\Abc\Omg\Why\Me\"`.

My approach is to first `reverse` the `string` and then **remove all** the `"\"` till we get **first** `char`, and the `reverse` it again.

How to do this in C#, is there any method for such operation?

Comment: I think you have `String path = @"C:\Abc\Omg\Why\Me\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\";`

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can just construct path using the `Path` static class:

```
string path = Path.GetFullPath(@"C:\Abc\Omg\Why\Me\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\");
```

After this operation, variable `path` will contain the minimal version:

```
C:\Abc\Omg\Why\Me\
```

Comment: Thanks @Zoran one should use only this for paths.

Comment: You may still have an issue if you need `Path.GetFullPath(@"C:\Windows\")` and `Path.GetFullPath(@"C:\Windows")` to have identical output. You could be passing paths to other systems that make different assumptions about path conventions. You may need a `.TrimEnd('\\')` or `.TrimEnd('\\') + '\\'` or equivalent to normalize the path depending on your use case.

Answer (score 13):

You can use `path.TrimEnd('\\')`. Have a look at the documentation for [`String.TrimEnd`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimend(v=vs.110).aspx).

If you want the trailing slash, you can add it back easily.

Comment: You should not treat file paths as simple strings. You should rely on .NET Framework's support for file paths because it knows it better. For example, who says that the segment delimiter is backslash? That is the system setting.

Comment: It's equally simple to use the `Path` class.

Comment: Thanks @DanielA.White since have accepted Zoran 's answer but yours will be used for further string manipulations.

Answer (score 3):

```
var path = @"C:\Abc\Omg\Why\Me\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\";
path = path.TrimEnd('\\') + '\\';
```

another solution is

```
var path = @"C:\Abc\Omg\Why\Me\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\";
path = Path.GetFullPath(path);
```

Comment: No need to manipulate strings. .NET Framework already has extensive support for file paths.

Comment: Agree. your solution is more elegant in this case. But what if Pranay wants remove another char in another string.

Comment: It's not that simple when it gets to paths. For example, `Path` class is defining the path separator character. What will be when we compile this code into a UWP app and then every now and then receive a forward slashes instead of backslashes? Better stick to strong types and let the framework and OS do their part.